# Raspberry pi database connection (monodevelop C#)

Tags: database-connection, raspberry-pi, monodevelop

I got on my raspberry pi a database.
Commandline:

```
mysql -u root -p   
pwd:******  
create database raspberrypidb;  
use raspberrypidb;  
create table users(.....);
```

Then in monodevelop I got this:

```
SqlDataAdapter objDA= new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM users","SERVER=192.168.1.100;

DATABASE=raspberrypidb:uid=root:pwd=******;");
```

Is this correct? What must I type by SERVER?

also a ERROR by

```
DataSet objDS=new DataSet(); // the type system.xmlSerialization ... is defined in an assembly that is not referer
```